# What to do if a php script suddenly won't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have this login code, which works last night before I slept. Nobody used my computer. But this morning suddenly stopped working. My other codes also  not working properly. Well in fact I made sure that they're all working before I left them. 
I reformatted my hard drive. I had a backup of the working project. I can't really understand why it wouldn't work. Anyone experienced this before?

```
<?php 




include('conn.php');








        $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['yname']);
        $pword = $_POST['pword'];
        $pwordmd5=md5($pword);



        $result = query_database("SELECT * FROM admin_table WHERE   Uneym = '$uname' AND Pwerd = '$pwordmd5'", "onstor", $link);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);



        if ($result) {
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['loginAdmin'] = "1";



                //added feb 5 2011

                $_SESSION['Uneym'] = $uname;






                query_database("UPDATE admin_table SET Current='1' WHERE   Uneym = '$uname' AND Pwerd = '$pwordmd5'", "onstor", $link);



                    header ("Location: adminpage.php");


            }



            else {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['loginAdmin'] = "";
                header ("Location: ../login.php");
            }   
        }
        else {
            $errorMessage = "Error logging on, please try again.";
        }











?>
```

I had this on php error log:

```
[12-Feb-2011 23:49:14] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6

[12-Feb-2011 23:49:14] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

 in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6

[12-Feb-2011 23:49:14] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6

    [12-Feb-2011 23:49:35] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6

    [12-Feb-2011 23:49:35] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

     in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6

    [12-Feb-2011 23:49:35] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6

    [12-Feb-2011 23:50:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6

    [12-Feb-2011 23:50:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

     in X:\wamp\www\pos\php\conn.php on line 6
```

Here's conn.php which is being pointed out by the error logs:

```
<?php



function open_connection($host, $user, $password){
    return mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

}

function close_connection($link){
    return mysql_close($link);

}

function query_database($query, $database, $link){
    mysql_select_db($database, $link);
    return mysql_query($query, $link);
}

function fetcher($result){
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

}

function query_checker($query){
    if(!$query){
    echo "error!".mysql_error();
}
    return mysql_error();

}

$link=open_connection('localhost','root', '1234');
?>
```

Also haven't modified conn.php, since its the first script that should be written when you want to connect to the database. And one more thing, before I reformatted, the whole project was one c drive. Now I'm on x drive. I'm not really sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Sounds the like server isn't responding or the connection is being blocked. Have you double checked that the mysql server is running?

Comment: yeah, I restarted all services from wampserver. Even tried to restart just the mysql service. I can't even access phpmyadmin

Comment: Umm.. you reformatted your harddrive? Because a script stopped working? Overkill much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database appears to be down. Try restarting your mysql service.

Answer (score 1):

Well basing simply on the errors you are getting, the problem is not in your code, but in your mysql server. Check server settings, that it is still running, that it has not been corrupted, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get the server started, it's possible that some other app might be conflicting with the server. Skype for example uses the same port and wamp might not start if Skype is open as well.

Comment: Is there an application which I could use to determine which application uses which port?